# Clusters with overlapping EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, apache-spark, amazon-ec2, hadoop-yarn

I have the following clusters with overlapping EC2 instances, for example: Yarn cluster and Memcached cluster are using same instances **2, 3, 4**; furthermore, each instance has different RAM, CPU, Core sizes, **will this potentially courses problem? or the clusters can do the balance by themselves?** Thank you!

Spark cluster: EC2 instances 2, 3, 5
Yarn cluster: EC2 instances 1, **2, 3, 4**, 5
Memcached database cluster: EC2 instances **2, 3, 4**, 6

```
instance 1: 512GB RAM, 2 vCPU,  2 cores  
instance 2: 1TB RAM,   8 vCPU,  4 cores    
instance 3: 2TB RAM,   6 vCPU,  6 cores    
instance 4: 256GB RAM, 2 vCPU,  2 cores  
instance 5: 2TB RAM,   16 vCPU, 4 cores    
instance 6: 4TB RAM,   4 vCPU,  8 cores
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clusters are not aware of this sharing; you need to configure resource allocations per host to avoid over-commitments.

If, for any node total resource allocation makes more than all RAM/Cores/Disk available, you are at risk (most often, at risk of spark task or yarn child being unable to start). Like, for instance 3 you can't allocate 1T to each service.

Like, at instance 3 you can't allocate 1T to each service.

As a side note, Spark can be run on yarn, so there is an options to reduce this to two clusters.

Comment: Thank you @patrungel, would I get more details about the last sentence? Do you mean that Spark cluster and Yarn cluster can share the same cluster machines? like 100% overlap?

Comment: Spark can be run as a Yarn application (that is, it can use Yarn as a resource manager for its jobs) so we are not speaking of overlap but of using _same_ cluster for both hadoop (mapred) AND spark jobs. In this case mapred and spark jobs are subject to common scheduling, hence you need not deal with two unrelated clusters.
This is quite a common setup, please refer to  http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html
Adding spark to existing Yarn cluster is rather a simple task.